# E200(ValidationError): stm32: Unable to bind the STM AI runtime with "cnn" c-model: []

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32f7

I am trying to validate my code to target device and get the following error.
Now i have tried the solutions in https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/428430042 except one. it says to choose M7 in single core mode. My board is STM32F769-DISCO and im not sure if its dual core or not. How do i resolve this error please?
[image]

Comment: for starters, check how many cores your MCU has. All documentation for it is available. How can you work with MCU without having at the very least its datasheet and reference manual at hand? It doesn't mean they have to be always open, but you definitely need to have them around.